# How to do PGP in Python (generate keys, encrypt/decrypt)

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp

I'm making a program in Python to be distributed to windows users via an installer.

The program needs to be able to download a file every day encrypted with the user's public key and then decrypt it.

So I need to find a Python library that will let me generate public and private PGP keys, and also decrypt files encrypted with the public key.

Is this something pyCrypto will do (documentation is nebulous)?  Are there other pure Python libraries?  How about a standalone command line tool in any language?

All I saw so far was GNUPG but installing that on Windows does stuff to the registry and throws dll's everywhere, and then I have to worry about whether the user already has this installed, how to backup their existing keyrings, etc.  I'd rather just have a python library or command line tool and mange the keys myself.

Update: pyME might work but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Python 2.4 which I have to use.

Comment: Please check this article - https://medium.com/@almirx101/pgp-key-pair-generation-and-encryption-and-decryption-examples-in-python-3-a72f56477c22

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need `PyCrypto` or `PyMe`, fine though those packages may be - you will have all kinds of problems building under Windows. Instead, why not avoid the rabbit-holes and do what I did? Use `gnupg 1.4.9`. You don't need to do a full installation on end-user machines - just `gpg.exe` and `iconv.dll` from the distribution are sufficient, and you just need to have them somewhere in the path or accessed from your Python code using a full pathname. No changes to the registry are needed, and everything (executables and data files) can be confined to a single folder if you want.

There's a module `GPG.py` which was originally written by Andrew Kuchling, improved by Richard Jones and improved further by Steve Traugott. It's available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090921072827/http://trac.t7a.org/isconf/browser/trunk/lib/python/isconf/GPG.py), but as-is it's not suitable for Windows because it uses `os.fork()`. Although originally part of `PyCrypto`, **it is completely independent of the other parts of `PyCrypto` and needs only gpg.exe/iconv.dll in order to work**.

I have a version (`gnupg.py`) derived from Traugott's `GPG.py`, which uses the `subprocess` module. It works fine under Windows, at least for my purposes - I use it to do the following:

- Key management - generation, listing, export etc.
- Import keys from an external source (e.g. public keys received from a partner company)
- Encrypt and decrypt data
- Sign and verify signatures

The module I've got is not ideal to show right now, because it includes some other stuff which shouldn't be there - which means I can't release it as-is at the moment. At some point, perhaps in the next couple of weeks, I hope to be able to tidy it up, add some more unit tests (I don't have any unit tests for sign/verify, for example) and release it (either under the original `PyCrypto` licence or a similar commercial-friendly license). If you can't wait, go with Traugott's module and modify it yourself - it wasn't too much work to make it work with the `subprocess` module.

This approach was a lot less painful than the others (e.g. `SWIG`-based solutions, or solutions which require building with `MinGW`/`MSYS`), which I considered and experimented with. I've used the same (`gpg.exe`/`iconv.dll`) approach with systems written in other languages, e.g. `C#`, with equally painless results.

P.S. It works with Python 2.4 as well as Python 2.5 and later. Not tested with other versions, though I don't foresee any problems.

Comment: Thanks that sounds perfect.  I had no idea I could just pull the exe out of gpg. Where will it put the keyring? Will this method cause any problems if the user already has gpg installed?  Any chance I could just see how your code does key generation, and key imports?

Comment: Also be sure to update us here when you release your final code.

Comment: When you call gpg, specify the path where you want the keyrings to be stashed using the --homedir argument. (This is already done for you using Traugott's module - there's a GPG class whose constructor takes a gnupghome parameter which you can set to this directory.) The pubring.gpg, secring.gpg and trustdb.gpg are created in the folder specified by --homedir.

I don't believe this will cause a problem if the user has gpg already installed - the --homedir argument should override any values in the registry.

Comment: Just make sure that the gpg which gets executed is your bundled copy - another installed copy (which might be on the path) may be a different version which would be wise to avoid just as a precautionary measure to head off any interoperability issues.

Comment: See http://paste.pocoo.org/show/125608/ for an excerpts from the unit tests for the module. This shows key generation and key importing.

Thanks for accepting the answer. I'll be sure to post a comment here when I release the code.

Comment: @VinaySajip  Hi there Vinay, thanks for your work on `gnupg`.  Could you comment on the relationship between this module and the [python-gnupg](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg) project on github?  Considering this answer is about 7 years old now - what's current, and which should a new user prefer?  (both projects seem well maintained and well documented, so the choice is not obvious)

Comment: @wim The other module is a fork (without any discussion with me) by another developer, and _not_ a drop-in replacement. Obviously, I would recommend my project as "the original and best"! The other project is GPLv3, my project is BSD. The other project cites a `shell=True` vulnerability which has not been in my project for a long time. To decide which to use, pick some features you need, and see which project has those/makes them easy to use.

Comment: The provided link within the answer is stale.

Comment: how do i go about using GPG.py, just drop it in my project folder and I can make reference to it?

Comment: @Sydney you can now install using `pip install python-gnupg` and then `import gnupg` etc,

Answer (score 39):

After a LOT of digging, I found a package that worked for me. Although it is said to support the generation of keys, I didn't test it. However I did manage to decrypt a message that was encrypted using a GPG public key. The advantage of this package is that it does not require a GPG executable file on the machine, and is a Python based implementation of the OpenPGP (rather than a wrapper around the executable). 
I created the private and public keys using GPG4win and kleopatra for windows
See my code below.

```
import pgpy
emsg = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file(<path to the file from the client that was encrypted using your public key>)
key,_  = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(<path to your private key>)
with key.unlock(<your private key passpharase>):
    print (key.decrypt(emsg).message)
```

Although the question is very old. I hope this helps future users.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can this actually perform encryption using the public key ? Also, a link to the package maybe helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Roee Anuar. Already used it to build a PGP based password protection program. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there an equivalent example where I can encrypt file using public key (pgpy) ?

Comment: Added an answer with code sample for pgpy and gpg to use just the public key exported file.

Comment: @lazyList here is the documentation that includes capabilities and installation instructions. https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 7):

PyCrypto supports PGP - albeit you should test it to make sure that it works to your specifications.

Although documentation is hard to come by, if you look through Util/test.py (the module test script), you can find a rudimentary example of their PGP support:

```
if verbose: print '  PGP mode:',
obj1=ciph.new(password, ciph.MODE_PGP, IV)
obj2=ciph.new(password, ciph.MODE_PGP, IV)
start=time.time()
ciphertext=obj1.encrypt(str)
plaintext=obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
end=time.time()
if (plaintext!=str):
    die('Error in resulting plaintext from PGP mode')
print_timing(256, end-start, verbose)
del obj1, obj2
```

Futhermore, PublicKey/pubkey.py provides for the following relevant methods:

```
def encrypt(self, plaintext, K)
def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
def sign(self, M, K):
def verify (self, M, signature):
def can_sign (self):
    """can_sign() : bool
    Return a Boolean value recording whether this algorithm can
    generate signatures.  (This does not imply that this
    particular key object has the private information required to
    to generate a signature.)
    """
    return 1
```

Comment: I don't see a way to generate keys, or accept another party's public key to encrypt data with.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, MODE_PGP in PyCrypto is legacy, experimental code that probably never worked right.  (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bug/996814).  Don't use it.  We'll be removing it from PyCrypto soon anyway.

Comment: Then what do you suggest, @dlitz?

Answer (score 3):

[PyMe](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/) does claim full compatibility with Python 2.4, and I quote:

> The latest version of PyMe (as of this
>   writing) is v0.8.0. Its binary
>   distribution for Debian was compiled
>   with SWIG v1.3.33 and GCC v4.2.3 for
>   GPGME v1.1.6 and Python v2.3.5,
>   v2.4.4, and v2.5.2 (provided in
>   'unstable' distribution at the time).
>   Its binary distribution for Windows
>   was compiled with SWIG v1.3.29 and
>   MinGW v4.1 for GPGME v1.1.6 and Python
>   v2.5.2 (although the same binary get
>   installed and works fine in v2.4.2 as
>   well).

I'm not sure why you say "it doesn't seem to be compatible with Python 2.4 which I have to use" -- specifics please?

And yes it does exist as a semi-Pythonic (SWIGd) wrapper on GPGME -- that's a popular way to develop Python extensions once you have a C library that basically does the job.

[PyPgp](http://softlayer.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/pypgp/pgp.py) has a much simpler approach -- that's why it's a single, simple Python script: basically it does nothing more than "shell out" to command-line PGP commands. For example, decryption is just:

```
def decrypt(data):
    "Decrypt a string - if you have the right key."
    pw,pr = os.popen2('pgpv -f')
    pw.write(data)
    pw.close()
    ptext = pr.read()
    return ptext
```

i.e., write the encrypted cyphertext to the standard input of `pgpv -f`, read pgpv's standard output as the decrypted plaintext.

PyPgp is also a very old project, though its simplicity means that making it work with modern Python (e.g., subprocess instead of now-deprecated os.popen2) would not be hard. But you still do need [PGP](http://www.pgp.com/) installed, or PyPgp won't do anything;-).

Comment: PyMe was this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030297/how-to-make-a-pyme-python-library-run-in-python-2-4-on-windows

Comment: Yeah, theit claim that I quoted (about Windows, specifically) is ill-founded (in Windows, only, extensions need to be compiled for specific versions of Python, so one compiled for 2.5 will not work for 2.4). All you need is to recompile (which requires MSVC 6.0).

Answer (score 3):

[M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) has PGP module, but I have actually never tried to use it. If you try it, and it works, please let me know (I am the current M2Crypto maintainer). Some links:

- [Module sources](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/PGP/)
- [Demo Script](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/demo/pgp/pgpstep.py)
- [unit tests](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_pgp.py)

**Update:** The PGP module does not provide ways to generate keys, but presumably these could be created with the lower level [RSA](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA-module.html), [DSA](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.DSA-module.html) etc. modules. I don't know PGP insides, so you'd have to dig up the details. Also, if you know how to generate these using openssl command line commands, it should be reasonably easy to convert that to M2Crypto calls.

Comment: Hmm, it looked promising but I don't see how to generate keys.

Comment: You might be able to generate the keys with the lower level RSA, DSA etc. modules.

Answer (score 3):

As other have noted, PyMe is the canonical solution for this, since it's based on GpgME, which is part of the GnuPG ecosystem.

For Windows, I strongly recommend to use [Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org) as the GnuPG distribution, for two reasons:

It's based on GnuPG 2, which, among other things, includes `gpg2.exe`, which can (finally, I might add :) start `gpg-agent.exe` on-demand (gpg v1.x can't).

And secondly, it's the only official Windows build by the GnuPG developers. E.g. it's entirely cross-compiled from Linux to Windows, so not a iota of non-free software was used in preparing it (quite important for a  security suite :).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full script that will:

1. Attempt to decrypt all the files in a given folder that were encrypted with your public key.
2. Write the new files to a specified folder.
3. Move the encrypted files to a specified folder.

The script also has everything you need to create and store your own private and public keys, check out the "First time set up" section below.

The idea is that you can schedule this script to run as often as you like, and it'll automatically decrypt data found and store it for you.

I hope this helps someone, this was a tricky project to figure out.

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Introduction, change log and table of contents
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Purpose: This script is used to encrypt and decrypt files using the PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) standard..
#
# Change date   Changed by      Description
# 2022-10-03    Ryan Bradley    Initial draft
# 2022-10-12    Ryan Bradley    Cleaned up some comments and table of contents. 
#
# Table of Contents
# [1.0] Hard-coded variables
# [1.1] Load packages and custom functions
# [1.3] First time set up
# [1.4] Define custom functions
# [2.0] Load keys and decrypt files
#
# Sources used to create this script, and for further reading:
# https://github.com/SecurityInnovation/PGPy/
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020320/how-to-do-pgp-in-python-generate-keys-encrypt-decrypt
# https://pypi.org/project/PGPy/
# https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-a-pgp-encryption-tool-with-python-19bae51b7fd
# https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ [1.1] Load packages 
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
import glob
import pgpy
import shutil
import io

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ [1.2] Hard-coded variables
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Define the paths to public and private keys
path_public_key = r'YOUR PATH HERE'
path_private_key = r'YOUR PATH HERE'

# Define paths to files you want to try decrypting
path_original_files = r'YOUR PATH HERE'
path_decrypted_files = r'YOUR PATH HERE'
path_encrypted_files= r'YOUR PATH HERE'

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ [1.3] First time set up
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#
# IMPORTANT WARNINGS!!!!
#  - Do NOT share your private key with anyone else. 
#  - You MUST have the associated private key that is is generated along with a public key 
#       if you want to be able to decrypt anything that is encryped with that public key. Do
#       not overwrite the existing keys unless you will never need any of the previously 
#       encryped data. 
#   - Do not generate new public and private keys unless you have a good reason to. 
#
# The following steps will walk you through how to create and write public and private keys to
# a network location. Be very careful where you store this information. Anyone with access
# to your private key can decrypt anything that was encryped with your public key.
#
# These steps only need to be performed one time when the script is first being 
# created. They are commented out intentionally, as they shouldn't need to be performed 
# every time the script is ran. 
# 
# Here's the a link to the documentation on this topic:
# https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

# # Load the extra things we need to define a new key
# from pgpy.constants import PubKeyAlgorithm, KeyFlags, HashAlgorithm, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm, CompressionAlgorithm
 
# # Gerate a new a primary key. For this example, we'll use RSA, but it could be DSA or ECDSA as well
# key = pgpy.PGPKey.new(PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign, 4096)

# # Define a new user 
# uid = pgpy.PGPUID.new('USER_NAME', comment='Generic user', email='YOUR_EMAIL')

# # Add the new user id to the key, and define all the key preferences.
# key.add_uid(uid, usage={KeyFlags.Sign, KeyFlags.EncryptCommunications, KeyFlags.EncryptStorage},
#             hashes=[HashAlgorithm.SHA256, HashAlgorithm.SHA384, HashAlgorithm.SHA512, HashAlgorithm.SHA224],
#             ciphers=[SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES256, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES192, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES128],
#             compression=[CompressionAlgorithm.ZLIB, CompressionAlgorithm.BZ2, CompressionAlgorithm.ZIP, CompressionAlgorithm.Uncompressed]
#             , is_compressed = True)

# # Write the ASCII armored public key to a network location.
# text_file = open(path_public_key, 'w')
# text_file.write(str(key.pubkey))
# text_file.close()

# # Write the ASCII armored private key to a network location.
# text_file = open(path_private_key, 'w')
# text_file.write(str(key))
# text_file.close()

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ [1.4] Define custom functions
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

def file_encrypt(path_original_file, path_encrypted_file, key_public):
    """
    A function that encrypts the content of a file at the given path and 
    creates an ecryped version file at the new location using the specified
    public key.
    """
    
    # Create a PGP file, compressed with ZIP DEFLATE by default unless otherwise specified
    pgp_file = pgpy.PGPMessage.new(path_original_file, file=True)
    
    # Encrypt the data with the public key
    encrypted_data = key_public.encrypt(pgp_file) 
    
    # Write the encryped data to the encrypted destination
    text_file = open(path_encrypted_file, 'w')
    text_file.write(str(encrypted_data))
    text_file.close()
   
def file_decrypt(path_encrypted_file, path_decrypted_file, key_private):
    """
    A function that decrypts the content of a file at path path and 
    creates a decrypted file at the new location using the given 
    private key.
    """

    # Load a previously encryped message from a file
    pgp_file = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file(path_encrypted_file)
    
    # Decrypt the data with the given private key
    decrypted_data = key_private.decrypt(pgp_file).message
   
    # Read in the bytes of the decrypted data
    toread = io.BytesIO()
    toread.write(bytes(decrypted_data))  
    toread.seek(0)  # reset the pointer 
   
    # Write the data to the location
    with open(path_decrypted_file, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(toread, f)
        f.close()
      
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ [2.0] Load keys and decrypt files
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Load your pre-generated public key from the network
key_public, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(path_public_key)

# Load your pre-generated public key from the network
key_private, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(path_private_key)

# Find and process any encrypted files in the landing folder
for file in glob.glob(path_original_files + '\*.pgp'):
    
    # Get the path to the file we need to decrypt
    path_encrypted_file = str(file)
    
    # Extract the file name
    parts = path_encrypted_file.split('\\')
    str_file_name = parts[len(parts)-1]
    str_clean_file_name = str_file_name[:-4]
    
    # Extract the file exension
    str_extension = str_clean_file_name.split('.')
    str_extension = str_extension[len(str_extension) - 1]
    
    # Create the path to the new decryped file, dropping the ".pgp" extension
    path_decrypted_file = path_decrypted_files + '\\' + str_clean_file_name
    
    # Create the path to the place we'll store the encryped file
    path_archived_encrypted_file = path_encrypted_files + '\\' + str_file_name
    
    # Decrypt the file
    try:
        file_decrypt(path_encrypted_file, path_decrypted_file, key_private)
        
        # Move the encryped file to its new location
        shutil.move(path_encrypted_file, path_archived_encrypted_file)
    except:
        print('DECRYPTION ERROR!')
        print(f'Unable to decrypt {path_encrypted_file}')
    
# Just for reference, here's how you would call the function to encrypt a file:
# file_encrypt(path_original_file, path_encrypted_file, key_public)
```

Answer (score 1):

To sign with only the exported public key file without a keyring.

With PGPy 0.5.2 (pure Python GPG RFC implementation):

```
key_fpath = './recipient-PUB.gpg'
     
rsa_pub, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(rkey_fpath)
rkey = rsa_pub.subkeys.values()[0]                                                                                                     
     
text_message = pgpy.PGPMessage.new('my msg')
encrypted_message = rkey.encrypt(text_message)
print encrypted_message.__bytes__()
```

With gpg 1.10.0 (gpgme Python bindings - former PyME):

```
rkey_fpath = './recipient-PUB.gpg'
cg = gpg.Context()
rkey = list(cg.keylist(source = rkey_fpath))                                                                                                                
 
ciphertext, result, sign_result = cg.encrypt('my msg', recipients=rkey, sign=False, always_trust=True)
print ciphertext
```

A simple benchmark in a for loop shows me that for this simple operation on my system PGPy is ~3x time faster than gpgme Python bindings (please do not take this statement as X is faster than Y: I will invite you to test in your environment).

Comment: Using PGP, Whats the Python function to generate public /private key  --> `rkey_fpath`

Comment: I tried your logic but got an error `TypeError: 'odict_values' object is not subscriptable
`. I have exported mypublic key to `my-pubkey.asc`

Answer (score 0):

I will just append to @Roee Anuar and his idea with pgpy

```
# pip install pgpy
from pgpy import PGPKey, PGPMessage
from pgpy.packet.packets import LiteralData
from pgpy.constants import CompressionAlgorithm
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import json

pass_phrase = "some_password_anyway"

# simple string
message = PGPMessage.new("42 is quite a pleasant number")
enc_message = message.encrypt(pass_phrase)
print(json.dumps(str(enc_message)))

# file
PGPMessage.filename = "filename.txt"
file_message = PGPMessage.new("/tmp/123", file=True)
enc_message = file_message.encrypt(pass_phrase)
print(json.dumps(str(enc_message)))
```

This is how you can encrypt strings and files.
Also I've implemented a way of encrypting data as a file:

```
# file from byte array and with custom name
msg = PGPMessage()
lit = LiteralData()
lit._contents = bytearray(msg.text_to_bytes("Some stuff in file"))
lit.filename = "any file name here even long ones are ok but do not exceed 192 bytes.txt"
lit.mtime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
lit.format = 'b'
lit.update_hlen()

msg |= lit
msg._compression = CompressionAlgorithm.ZIP

enc_message = msg.encrypt(pass_phrase)
print(json.dumps(str(enc_message)))
```