# Encrypting/Decrypting file with python

Tags: python, encryption

Is there a way to use python to encrypt/decrypt a file (something like Axcrypt)?

Comment: is the ruby tag there by accident? I would fix it for you, but I can't...

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with `python` instead of `ruby`, or are the title and question body in error?

Comment: was there a ruby tag? sorry didn't notice it

Answer (score 1):

How about [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020320/how-to-do-pgp-in-python-generate-keys-encrypt-decrypt), which talks about encrypting/decrypting with PGP?

Answer (score 1):

check
http://github.com/slideinc/PyECC , 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptopy/ and 
http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/
(found all by search "crypto" at http://pypi.python.org/pypi )

Answer (score 0):

Go here in the python docs for modules available for encryption: http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for encrypting as well as decrypting..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import nacl.secret
import nacl.utils
import base64
from pyblake2 import blake2b
import getpass

print "### ENCRYPTION"
key = blake2b(digest_size=16)
key.update(getpass.getpass("PASSWORD:"))
key = key.hexdigest()

print "key: %s" % key
box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)

# This is our message to send, it must be a bytestring as SecretBox will
#   treat is as just a binary blob of data.
msg = b"whohooäööppöööo"
print "msg: %s" % msg
nonce = nacl.utils.random(nacl.secret.SecretBox.NONCE_SIZE)
print "nonce: %s" % nacl.encoding.HexEncoder.encode(nonce)
encrypted = box.encrypt(msg, nonce, encoder=nacl.encoding.HexEncoder)
print "cipher: %s " % encrypted

print "### DECRYPTION"
key = blake2b(digest_size=16)
key.update(getpass.getpass("PASSWORD:"))
key = key.hexdigest()

nonce = None
print "nonce: %s" % nonce
print "key: %s" % key
box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)

msg = encrypted
print "msg: %s" % msg

plain = box.decrypt(ciphertext=msg,encoder=nacl.encoding.HexEncoder)
print "plain: %s" % plain
```